# How to integrate redcloth with coderay

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redcloth, coderay

I want to use syntax highlighting along with redcloth.

The description of coderay says:

> Fast and easy syntax highlighting for selected languages, written in
>   Ruby. Comes with RedCloth integration and LOC counter. [1](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/coderay)

But I did not find a documentation about how to do this?

Where should I put the code to do the hightlighting? I thought about putting it into `module ApplicationHelper` is this a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OPTION 1:**

Simpe as this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/207-syntax-highlighting?autoplay=true
When using rails3 change helper to this:

```
  def coderay(text) 
    text.gsub!(/\<code(?: lang="(.+?)")?\>(.+?)\<\/code\>/m) do 
      code = CodeRay.scan($2, $1).div(:css => :class) 
      "<notextile>#{code}</notextile>" 
    end 
    return text.html_safe 
  end
```

If you use HAML you will want to use ~ sign:

```
~ raw textilize(coderay(...))
```

**OPTION 2:**

CodeRay has built-in support for RedCloth.

1. Add required gem files into your Gemfile.

> ```
> gem "RedCloth", :require => 'redcloth'
> gem 'coderay', :require => ['coderay', 'coderay/for_redcloth']
> ```

1. Render the code string like you would do it with RedCloth (~ instead of = because I using HAML).

> ```
> ~ raw textilize("Some code here @that should@ be formated.")
> ~ raw textilize("Some code here @[ruby]that should@ be formated.")
> ```

1. You can also render a file.

> ```
> # File at /my/file/path/filename.doc
> h1. My title 
> bc[ruby].. # Nekaj za napisat 
> def self.myfun   
> puts "asdas" 
> end
>
> # Inside your view file
> ~ raw textilize(File.read("/my/file/path/filename.doc"))
> ```

I prefere the second option.

You can find more about styling with Textile markup language at [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_(markup_language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29)

Comment: Hey @xpepermint - thanks for the info. I followed option 2 and am getting my code on a single line. Do I have to make any special changes when adding my code into the DB? Cheers!

Comment: what is slim's equivalent for haml's `~` ?
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames

Comment: What's the erb equivalent?

Comment: what is $2 and $1? Where can we find a table or documentation for it? It's certainly not in the official coderay reference